# SRGS - GRXML parsing via text input in java

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, grammar, voicexml

I have an existing IVR voice application which uses SRGS .grxml grammar files.  In the IVR our speech recognizer (Nuance) uses these grammars to take spoken input and return some values based on the particular grammar specified.

I'm trying to find a java based tool which would use these same grammar files but allow me to send plain text in to be parsed according to the rules of the grammar.

I've seen sphinx4 and they have a recognizer but it only uses microphone input from what I can tell.  I'm really looking for something like nuance's "parseTool" which given the grammar and a sample text will output the results of the grammar, but I need it within a Java class.

Does anyone know of any tools like this?

Comment: Hi, can you be a bit more specific about your use case? Why do you need to do that in Java?

Comment: I've written a java based SRGS/SISR parser in Java.  I've been working with the JVoiceXML project to improve the ability to test VoiceXML projects with the codebase.  I don't believe this code has been publicized yet. If you are interested, use my profile information to find and contact me and I can share the code with you directly.

Comment: Thank you Jim!  I will contact you!

Comment: Shemeway,  I am writing a tool that will "browse" our existing IVR applications and present the interface as plain text instead of audio files.  The idea is to SMS enable an IVR application.  So I would like to leverage existing grammars written for a voice application, by inputing the texted user input and output the same information our grammars do now for spoken input.